# How to calculate the standard derivation of an image quickly using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

My question is: how can we calculate the standard derivation of an image very quickly using opencv? My solution is as follows:

```
double std(const cv::Mat &img)
{
    double squareSum=0;
    double sum=0;
    int elementSum;
    elementSum = img.rows*img.cols;
    for(int row = 0; row<img.rows; row++)
    {
        const unsigned char *p = img.ptr(row);
        for(int col=0; col<img.cols; col++)
        {
            sum += *p;
            squareSum += (*p)*(*p);
            p++;
        }
    }

    double mean = sum/elementSum;
    return(squareSum/elementSum- mean*mean);
}
```

In my code I assume that the image has only one band. Do you have some ideas of further improving the above code or do you have other solutions?

Comment: What's wrong with [`meanStDev`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#meanstddev) ?

Comment: @RogerRowland Thanks, and I do not know this function.